# Tkinter - importing and learning

Tags: tkinter

Two part question for a relative newbie:

1) How to import a module, specifically tkinter? I'm using 2.7 and on OSX, if that helps.

2) Do you know any tutorial sites for such a thing?

Comment: `import Tkinter`? & what is _such a thing_ here? Importing modules or `Tkinter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) I use this one http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm although they say

> "This is an incomplete draft version, last updated in November 2005"

Comment: Thank you, I found another tutorial but I've been using this one sporadically.